# Emitting a constant force from an object(Leaf blower Mechanic) C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just about to tackle a new project where the core game mechanic is covering up dead bodies killed by the mafia with leaves using a leafblower.

You need to cover them well enough to not draw attention when the police question you.

The only problem I can see with this project is how to create this leafblower mechanic.
Off the top of my head I can think of attaching an empty object to my leaf blower which has a constant [rigibody.AddExplosiveForce] that procs on mouse click but thats it.

What should I be looking at and what would be a logical way to create this? You do not need to write the whole code for me, I just wan't to know what tools or scripting API I need to consider.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try continuous adding force using [`Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html). Or calculate directions and try [`Rigidbody.AddForce()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

Basically `Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce` is working as `Rigidbody.AddForce`, but uses sphere to calculate `Vector3`. If you need to emit it continuously, you should just use it in `FixedUpdate()` and list of object you can get by using `Raycasts` or simple `Trigger Collider`, for example `Capsule Collider`.

[image: Leaf Blower]

You could use Collider Capsule like this ↑↑↑. And in `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter`:

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other) {
     if (other.gameobject.tag != "leaf") return;
     // Your AddForce here. 
     // Also you can get exact point of collsion by using
     // other.contacts and use this as AddForce argument.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you v much :)

Comment: second thoughts, im confused as ****. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Edited above ;)

Comment: ty :)))))))))))))))))))